# How to check for Jupyter active notebooks through command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, amazon-emr

I have an AWS EMR running Jupyterhub version 0.8.1+ that I want to check if there are any active notebooks that are running any code.
I've tried the below commands but they don't seem to output what I'm looking for here since the users server is always running and notebooks can be running without any code being executed.

```
# only lists running servers and jovyan is always running.
sudo docker exec jupyterhub jupyter notebook list
# No useful information outputted
curl -k -i -H "Accept: application/json" "https://localhost:9443/api/sessions"
# always lists processes regardless of running notebooks
ps aux | grep ipykernel
# The last_activity only updates when a user creates a new file or folder in the ui.
curl -k https://localhost:9443/hub/api/users/$user -H "Authorization: token $admin_token" | jq -r .last_activity
curl -k https://localhost:9443/hub/api/users -H "Authorization: token $admin_token" | jq -r .last_activity
```

Im following this AWS blog to check if the entire EMR is idle before terminating the cluster but they never seemed to have fully implemented the jupyter checks.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimize-amazon-emr-costs-with-idle-checks-and-automatic-resource-termination-using-advanced-amazon-cloudwatch-metrics-and-aws-lambda/
Most of the files referenced can be found in Github https://github.com/septian-putra/emr-monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see if a notebook is "idle" for "busy" you can run `curl -ks https://localhost:9443/user/jovyan/api/kernels -H "Authorization: token ${admin_token}"`
With this command all you need to do is put it in a simple if statement with a `grep -q` in order to get a true false idle value.

```
if [ $(curl -ks https://localhost:9443/user/jovyan/api/kernels -H "Authorization: token ${admin_token}" | grep -q "busy") ]; then
    JUPYTER_BUSY_NOTEBOOKS=1
else
    JUPYTER_BUSY_NOTEBOOKS=0
fi
```

(curl -ks For a silent output and to ignore ssl. jovyan being my admin user)

Documentation
https://jupyter-kernel-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websocket-mode.html#http-resources
/api/sessions might also be useful to look at.